# Printing all possible words from a 2D array of characters

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Stumbled upon this interview question recently,

Given a 2-dimensional array of characters and a dictionary in which a word can be searched in `O(1)` time. Need to print all the words from array which are present in dictionary. Word can be formed in any direction but has to end at any edge of array.(Need not worry much about the dictionary)

**Input:**

```
a f h u n
e t a i r
a e g g o
t r m l p
```

**Output:**

```
after
hate
hair
air
eat
tea
```

Note: Here "egg" is not a dictionary word because its not ending at the edge of array.

I've seen similar questions before, but was never able to think of a good algorithm to solve these kind of problems. Any help on how to approach these kind of problems (forming words from arrays of characters) will be highly helpful.

(The only way I could think of is to find all possible permutations of characters in the 2D array, and check if it ends on the edge of the array, and check if the permutation is a valid word from the dictionary in O(1) time)

Comment: Other than `dict.contains(word)`, what else are you allowed to do with the dictionary? Can you for example pre-process it to build some data structure?

Comment: You cannot do any pre-processing with the dictionary, you can preprocess the array in case you choose to.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the same cell several times when forming a word?

Comment: Can you repeat the same element twice? If so - assume infinite dictionary `(ea)+` and the array `[e,a]` your answer is ea,eaea,eaeaea,... (for infinity), so basically the problem  without any information in the dictionary is equivalent to the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: How can you be allowed to preprocess one but not another? Is this a homework?

Comment: @hamstergene: Since the dictionary is a "black box" and the array is a "glass box", it makes perfect sense. He also mentioned this is an interview question.

Comment: You could save some time if `dict.isPrefix(string)` method exists. Outside of that I don't see it being any different than a DFS starting from every place in the input. Assuming you cannot re-use the same character multiple times, like @amit points outs.

Comment: Why the word "porn" is not listed in output?

Comment: You can build a trie out of the dictionary. Then keep generating the permutations one by one and check if the prefix is available in the dictionary. If the prefix is present, you will proceed with further permutations of that prefix else terminate that recursive step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the array into a graph so that each cell `[i,j]` 
has an edge shared with each one of its 4 neighbors `[i+1,j], [i-1,j], [i,j+1], [i,j-1]`.
Then run DFS at each array-edge-cell and and keep checking the dictionary whether 
the word in reverse is in it.

Comment: Note that approach is feasible only if you are bounded to return to each element only a finite number of times.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention anything about a character can be used only once - so without this restriction is problem of "Can we generate k (or more) different words?" is **undecideable**.<sup>1</sup>.

(With a constraint on the number of "visites" per element there are finite number of possibilities and the claim and proof does not hold of course).

**Proof:**

It is known that there is no algorithm `A` that can decide if a terminating algorithm `B` returns `true` for `k` or more different inputs. (will look for citation for this claim later if needed, trust me for now).

We will show that given an algorithm `A` that says if there are `k` or more generated words - we can decide if there are `k` or more different inputs that yield "true":

1. Let the (terminating) algorithm that decides if there are `k` or
   more generated words be `M`.
2. Without loss of generality - assume binary alphabet (we can represent everything with it).
3. Let:

   ```
    array = 0 1 
            0 1
   ```

   Note we can generate any binary word while walking on this array.

**Algorithm A:**

**input:** algorithm B, natural number n

output: true if and only if algorithm B answers "true" for n or more different inputs.

**The algorithm**:

(1) use `B(word)` as the black box dictionary - if the answer is true, then `word` is in dictionary.

(2) use `array` as the array.

(3) Run M on (array,dictionary,n), and answer like it.

Note that if M answered true -> there are `n` or more accepted words -> there are `n` or more different inputs to B that yields true (definition of dictionary and since we can generate every input with array) -> the answer to the problem is true.

(if the algorithm answered false the proof is similar).

**QED**

**Conclusion:**

If we can repeat a character in the array more then a once (or to be exact - unbounded number of times) - then **the problem is unsolveable without any information on the dictionary.**

---

(1) An undecideble problem is a problem where there is no algorithm that can answer TRUE/FALSE correctly in 100% of the cases - For every algorithm, there is some case where the algorithm will get "stuck" in an infinite loop (or give a wrong answer). The most common of "undecideable" problems is the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) - which says - there is no algorithm `A` that can take any algorithm `B` and answer if `B` stops for some input `w`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

I suppose that I have an M*N array and there is no restriction in searching words. For example 'rood' and 'door' are 2 different words as being reversed of each other.

Start from the first letter (left, top). In this case, it is 'a'. And check adjacents if there are any words in dictionary(suppose there are words starting with 'ae' and 'af' ) Check whether they are already words or not and the index of the last letter is 0 or M-1 or N-1. If not, add them to a queue to look later. By turns, check all queued substrings like this and finish this this phase by prosessing all values in queue. Then check second letter and go on up to the last member of array. Like this, you will be able to check all possible words.

It works on one of my problems like this but Im not sure if you are looking also for complexity.

Comment: The problem is that OP said that the dictionary is black box: you can only test whether a given word occurs in it - so not whether there exist words with a given prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

 /**
 * Given a 2-dimensional array of characters and a
 * dictionary in which a word can be searched in O(1) time.
 * Need to print all the words from array which are present
 * in dictionary. Word can be formed in any direction but
 * has to end at any edge of array.
 * (Need not worry much about the dictionary)
 */
public class DictionaryWord {
private static char[][] matrix = new char[][]{
        {'a', 'f', 'h', 'u', 'n'},
        {'e', 't', 'a', 'i', 'r'},
        {'a', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'o'},
        {'t', 'r', 'm', 'l', 'p'}
};
private static int dim_x = matrix.length;
private static int dim_y = matrix[matrix.length -1].length;
private static Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //dictionary
    wordSet.add("after");
    wordSet.add("hate");
    wordSet.add("hair");
    wordSet.add("air");
    wordSet.add("eat");
    wordSet.add("tea");

    for (int x = 0; x < dim_x; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < dim_y; y++) {
            checkAndPrint(matrix[x][y] + "");
            int[][] visitedMap = new int[dim_x][dim_y];
            visitedMap[x][y] = 1;
            recursion(matrix[x][y] + "", visitedMap, x, y);
        }
    }
}

private static void checkAndPrint(String word) {
    if (wordSet.contains(word)) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}

private static void recursion(String word, int[][] visitedMap, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = Math.max(x - 1, 0); i < Math.min(x + 2, dim_x); i++) {
        for (int j = Math.max(y - 1, 0); j < Math.min(y + 2, dim_y); j++) {
            if (visitedMap[i][j] == 1) {
                continue;
            } else {
                int[][] newVisitedMap = new int[dim_x][dim_y];
                for (int p = 0; p < dim_x; p++) {
                    for (int q = 0; q < dim_y; q++) {
                       newVisitedMap[p][q] = visitedMap[p][q];
                    }
                }
                newVisitedMap[i][j] = 1;
                checkAndPrint(word + matrix[i][j]);
                recursion(word + matrix[i][j], newVisitedMap, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}